# Python Django project - move div class footer into body

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, css

I'm creating a blog with python and django. Most of it has been fine up until i've just tried to create the footer. The footer display's fine on the home page but when you click into the blog post the footer gets constrained by the content container and row div class.
When you look at this in firefox dev inspector and DOM it's showing that my footer div is sat within the content container and row, and not in the body. Most things i've usually managed to find the answer for but this is driving me nuts. I think i'm either missing something or i'm not asking the right question.

1. I don't understand why it's just the footer div that has been put within the content container / row div and nothing else that is effected in the same way.
2. Is there anyway to amend this without using jquery / jscript and changing the parentElement node?
3. If i have to amend this with jscript, where exactly do i have to amend it, and with what?

Thanks

```css
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
  <div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
        Copyright &copy 2017
    </div>
  </footer>
```

[firefox dev inspector image - sat in row div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2coSv.jpg)

[firefox dev inspector image - moved to body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtETw.jpg)

Comment: If you open divs in your blog that you don't close, then the footer will end up in the row.

Comment: Is the div closing your container missing the >?

Comment: Apologies, not sure how the > went missing, but no i closed the /div tag and it's still the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if there are opening  tags that don't have closing  tags. For example, if your blog looked like this,

```
{% block content %}

  <div id="open_tag_1">
      <div id="open_tag_2">

{% endblock %}
```

The  tags that you expect to be closing `<div class="content container">` and `<div class="row">` will actually be used to close `<div id="open_tag_1">` and `<div id="open_tag_2">`.

`<footer>` will then be inside `<div class="row">`.

Comment: Yes i see what you mean, but surely the 3 closing </div> tags close off the content container, row and col opening tags?
And also the footer is then seperated and also opening a new div with the div class footer?

Comment: And also this works perfectly on the home page but it's when viewing a specific blog post in detail it it get aligned under the row div

Comment: I assume the content block is different for the blog and home page. If your blog has unclosed div tags in your blog, then row or container might not be closed correctly. Do not use your browser's developer tools to look at the html, because they will auto-close tags for you.

Comment: I've pasted the content block code above, again i've checked it and all div's seem to be closed inside and i don't have any code out of the content block.
Yeah thanks i was just using the dev tools to see what was happening as i couldn't see anything in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the blog post detail page

```html
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
          {% if post.published_date %}
              {{ post.published_date }}
              by Matt Cheetham
          {% else %}
              <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'blog.views.post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
          {% endif %}
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
              <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_remove' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
          {% endif %}
          <div class="postview">
            {{ post.title }}
          </div>
          <p>{{ post.text|safe }}</p>
          <div class="comment">
            <div class="date">
          <h3>Comments</h3>
          <br>
              <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add comment</a>
              <br>
              <br>
          {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
              {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}
                  {{ comment.created_date }}
                  {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
                      <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                      <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
                <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
                <p>{{ comment.text|safe }}</p>
              </div>
              {% endif %}
          {% empty %}
              <p>No comments here yet...</p>
          {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```